# Queue to gather outputs from threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application that executes two threads in parallel, each performing some action, which at the end results in an integer being produced. In my main thread, i would like to perform some operation on the int produced by each Thread A and Thread B (call them int a and int b respectively) and then output them in the order in which each thread spits them out. So in essence, I am running each thread at regular intervals (say every 2 seconds) and each of the threads spits out an integer which i manipulate and print out in the order of their cration.

In order to do this, how can i aggregate together the ints for each thread that need to be printed by the gui thread? Can i use a queue for each thread that the main thread observes and when it gets updated, the main gui manipulates and outputs them? How can i write such a queue?

The code for my thread is as follows:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Thread(new t1()).start(//TODO: pass in some parameter that this
                                   //thread will write to); 
        new Thread(new t2()).start();
    }
}, 0, period);
```

Comment: Queue, wait() and notify(). These are your keywords. Dont have time to elaborate now, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this solution, you may find it useful. It use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` for thread-safe operations on the queue.

```
final Queue<Integer> queue1 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
final Queue<Integer> queue2 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();

final Random r = new Random();

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {             
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Thread 1
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //even numbers
                queue1.add(r.nextInt(50)*2);
            }
        }).start();

        //Thread 2
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //odd numbers
                queue2.add(r.nextInt(50)*2 + 1);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}, 0, 2000);

//Main thread (maybe GUI)
while (true){
    while (!queue1.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Thread-1: " + queue1.poll());
    }
    while (!queue2.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Thread-2: " + queue2.poll());
    }
}
```

*Edit*

What you really need is a Producer-Consumer (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). To solve that we will use another queue `ArrayBlockingQueue`, because this data structure let us block until something is produced (or consumed).

```
final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue1 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1024);
final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue2 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1024);

final Random r = new Random();          

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //don't create threads here, this is already a thread, just produce the numbers
            //If the queue is full `BlockingQueue.put()` will block until the consumer consume numbers.

            //Producer even number
            queue1.put(r.nextInt(50)*2);

            //Producer odd number
            queue2.put(r.nextInt(50)*2 + 1);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, 0, 2000);

//Now we create the threads that will take numbers from the producer. Don't worry about the `while (true)`, it is not wasting resources because `BlockingQueue.take()` will block the thread until something is produced.

//Consumer 1
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true){
                System.out.println("Thread-1: " + queue1.take());

                //Or update some UI component
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();

//Consumer 2
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true){
                System.out.println("Thread-2: " + queue2.take());

                //Or update some UI component
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: The thing is, the timer does not have direct access to the queue from within the run(). the queue resides in another class. So can i just pass it in and when i add inside the run(), the queue in the other class will also see it get added. in other words, would the queue by passed by ref?

Comment: @JohnBaum Accessing the queue is another thing, you can do it the way you prefer. For demonstration purposes I use a final variable, but you can have a singleton, call a getter from an object, etc...

Comment: is a while(true) the only way to keep checking if new queue data is available? Is there a notification based system i can use that doesnt block the ui?

Comment: @JohnBaum I use `while(true)` because my thread is not a GUI thread, like AWT "Event Dispatch Thread", that keep waiting (natively) for events. In GUI app you may want to check the queue when an event happens (like click in a button).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Its just that, my threads are running in the background on a timer so there is no real "event" as such that triggers them, its more like every x sec run the threads and update the ui with the results. So how can i tell when to update the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) framework which uses [Callables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of Runnables. One of the advantage of using Callable is that it provides a `call` method analogous to Runnable `run` method, but `call` method can `return` a value. So in your case, you can return the integer values from your two threads and then can use them in your main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a queue to the constructor of both the threads.

Override the offer/add method of the queue you passed, and add your logic to call the gui main thread here, basically call the listeners after calling the base class call.